# Ping is fast but web is slow?

Tags: network

I have my MacBook Pro connected to a cell-enabled iPad.  Ping to stackexchange.com is less than 60 ms.  But web pages are taking ages.  A robot detector for a meta question has been there for several minutes, and the checkbox has still not appeared.

Mail is showing connection errors, as is iTunes.  I don't think it's cell filtering, as various things have worked fine on other occasions.  Maps was a little bit slow downloading imagery but not bad.

I thought perhaps having both USB and WiFi hotspot might be interfering with each other, but turning off WiFi didn't change anything.

The cell signal is poor in this apartment.  But wouldn't that slow down ping by the same percentage as anything else?

Comment: Ping (how fast a small amount of data takes to travel) is different than download speed (how much data your computer can get through your router per second). It's download speed that determines how fast websites load. Just search google for "what's my download speed" and know that as a baseline any speed 25 MBps or faster means the web page will load "fast" IMHO.

Comment: @owlswipe is absolutely correct.  You are confusing response time with bandwidth which is analogous to comparing a Ferrari with a pickup saying the Ferrari is fast but it takes forever to move the contents of your apartment.  Try using [SpeedTest.net](http://www.speedtest.net/) to get a real world result of your Internet speed.

Comment: @Allan Thanks!! I've posted an expanded answer as well.

Comment: @WGroleau Let me know if my answer helps or not, and please let me know if you need anything else with this, I'd be happy to help out!

Comment: Speedtest equivalent (ookla) is where I got the numbers that inspired the question.  And after further experimentation, I think it measures theory better than reality.  Two reasons: (1) When I supposedly had a good connection, Skype's performance was far worse than on a reportedly worse connection elsewhere; (2) without changing my location, I.e., same cell tower, I could get download speeds ranging from 0..29 MBps to 42.31 MBps by selecting different test servers.  The fastest was 8000 miles away, the third slowest (9.23) is a few miles and belongs to my cell provider!

Answer (score 1):

> Ping to stackexchange.com is less than 60 ms. But web pages are taking ages.

You're conflating Ping speed and actual download speed, something that can't be done.

[**Ping**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)) (how fast a small amount of data takes to travel) is different than [**download speed**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_(computing)) (how much data your computer can get through your router per second). It's download speed that determines how fast websites load, not your ping score (as an aside, a ping as high as 60ms indicates to me that your cellular connection is pretty slow, for me ~10ms comes with fast download speeds on LTE).

So how can you find out your download speed? Just search google for `what's my download speed` (or go to [speedtest.net](https://speedtest.net)) to measure it. As a baseline, any speed 25 Mbps or faster means the web page will load at a speed I would perceive as "fast" and any speed below 2 Mbps is close to unbearable.

---

**tl;dr:** Having low ping does not mean websites will necessarily load fast; download speeds determine how fast a webpage will load.

Comment: OK, now I realize that ping is a single packet, while a download will be numerous packets that have to be sequenced and reassembled.  But there is also the issue that the path for a speedtest may be faster or slower than the path to the web server I want.  And it can also change.  Right now, stack exchange seems instantaneous, and I am right where I was when I posted the question.

Comment: @WGroleau Indeed, numerous things can fluctuate. I think Stack Exchange has enough power to handle all of its users without any major slowdowns (though of course, this differs between websites and that's why some load faster than others—it's their servers). That difference in speed is probably explained by congestion on your cell network: other people around you connecting to the same cell tower can make it considerably slower (for instance, at sporting events, during power outages, etc.).